# Jquery UI Dialog not closing within ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was  trying to send ajax  call from submit  of dialog  button,
And on success of ajax i need to close dialog with another dialog 
I have a Dialog box code  below

```
$("#Forgot-password").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    heigth: 50,
    width: 320,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function () {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            bValid = bValid && checkLength(forgotUsername, "username", 3, 16)
            if (bValid) {
                $(".validateTips").text("Wait....");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    async:true,
                    data: { "REQUESTTYPE": 1, "USERNAME": forgotUsername.val() },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required.");
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $("#dialog-forgot-message").dialog("open");
                    },

                }); 

            }
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required.");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required.");
    }
});
```

So, Success  code is not working, Can any one help me out , where i am  wrong here

Comment: in url what is the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an error handler to your Ajax code and log the error to see what went wrong.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    async:true,
    data: { "REQUESTTYPE": 1, "USERNAME": forgotUsername.val() },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required.");
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $("#dialog-forgot-message").dialog("open");
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
 });
```

It will log an object, if you expand it you should be able to find an error message. Usually it's a fault in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(result) {
    $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required.");
    $("#Forgot-password").dialog("close");
    ^^^^^use dialog box id here 
    $("#dialog-forgot-message").dialog("open");
},
```

the reason is in ajax it cant get the the reference of `$(this)` so close by **Id**

Comment: :: even   $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required."); this part of code is  working, Actually my code is not hitting Success  part of code,

Comment: I have tried to  alert within success  but alert  box is not hit :(